# Deque rotate returns None type

Tags: python, numpy, deque

I am trying to rotate a numpy array object to the right or left by some distance. The way I am doing this is the following:

1. I cast it into deque object
2. use rotate method of deque object.
3. recast the type back to numpy array.

For example, I rotate the array, called myarray, to the right by 2 elements.

```
deque(myarray)
myarray = myarray.rotate(2)
print myarray
```

What I get is not an array, but None. Could someone help me out on this problem?

Comment: `rotate` rotates the deque in-place.

Comment: read the doc. rotate does not return anything

Comment: Are you sure that all this conversion is faster than just slicing and reassembling the array?

Comment: You might be interested in `numpy.roll`.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, I know there are many ways to do it. I also tried different ways. They worked. I wanna know why I fail in this way.

Comment: @roippi, perhaps you would post an answer, as that seems to be the solution?

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by roippi, `rotate` rotates the deque in place. The code should be following

```
deque(myarray)
myarray.rotate(1)
```

Or rotate the array as Bi Rico suggested.

```
roll(myarray, 1)
```

There are many other ways to do the job, for example slicing.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this a comment/ clarification/ summary on stardusts answer (can't comment due to reputation) with a complete code example:

combining startdusts answer with the comment from njzk2 (rotate doesn't return anything to print) you get the whole picture.

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> myarray = [1,2,3,4]
>>> myarray = deque(myarray)
>>> print myarray
deque([1,2,3,4])
>>> myarray.rotate(1)
>>> print myarray
deque([4,1,2,3])
```